# Django Models, Gathering models.AutoField number while overriding save() method

Tags: python, django, django-models, model

I have a Django Model for **Users** and then a Separate model for **AccessLevels**.

When saving a **User** using Django's ORM, I want to also place an entry in the **AccessLevels** table.

My issue is that the **PK** of **AccessLevels** is the **PK** of **Users** and I cannot seem to override the `save()` method and gather the value of `id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)`.

Here is my relevant code:

```
class Users(models.Model):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    # pk
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)

    # client_id
    client_id = models.IntegerField(null=False, blank=False, default="-1")

    ...

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        AccessLevel(user_id=self.id,
                client_id=self.client_id).save(using='default')

        print('Access Level Set for User while saving')
        super(Users, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Here is the important part of **AccessLevel**

```
class AccessLevel(models.Model):

    # pk
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)

    # this is the id for the user, but I get null value
    user_id = models.IntegerField(null=False, blank=False, default="-1")

    client_id = models.IntegerField(null=False, blank=False, default="-1")
```

When I call this code I get the error.

```
root_user = Users(username='root',
                      email='root',
                      first_name='root',
                      last_name='root',
                      phone='root',
                      password=make_password(default_root_pw),
                      type='root').save(using='default')
```

Here is the error

**django.db.utils.IntegrityError: null value in column "user_id" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (3, null, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0).**

Comment: Don't do that! Primary keys are typically seen as "blackboxes". Yes these are numbers, but aiming to harmonize two primary keys is really looking for trouble. Furthermore it is not Django that "distributes" primary keys, but the database itself. This guarantees that the primary keys distributed are unique (unless something is wrong with the database of course).

Comment: Furthermore you should use `ForeignKey`s to relate to another object, not `IntegerField`s. `ForeignKey`s will add extra constraints to the database, that guarantee that the value in such columns always refer to an (existing) record with such primary key.

Comment: no that would result in an even more severe anti-pattern: *data duplication*. It is better to use `ForeignKey`s. Django also provide programmer convenience for that, since the objects that you relate to, are lazily loaded in memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, absolutely do not use IntegerFields for those values. They are foreign keys, you should use the ForeignKey field. These should be called `user` and `client` - note that you can still access the underlying IDs as before.

(Also, there's no need to explicitly declare an `id` field; and you should almost never override `__init__` in a model, but especially there is never any point overriding a method that only calls the super method. Just remove that.)

```
class AccessLevel(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey('Users', null=False, blank=False)
    client = models.ForeignKey('Client', null=False, blank=False)

class Users(models.Model):
    client = models.ForeignKey('Client', null=False, blank=False)
```

Now, for your actual problem, the id is assigned by the database, which doesn't happen until after save. So you should create your related item *after* that.

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(Users, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    AccessLevel(user_id=self.id,
            client_id=self.client_id).save(using='default')

    print('Access Level Set for User while saving')
```

Another way of creating the item, which might be a bit clearer, is to use the accessor provided by the foreign key:

```
self.accesslevel_set.create(client_id=self.client_id)
```

Finally though, this is probably better as [a post-save signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/signals/), rather than in the save method.

Comment: Ahh okay, understood. Thanks for the insight!

Comment: Just wanted to note for anybody stumbling across this answer, it is very cool how Django's ORM works with Foreign Keys. Basically, it stores the PK of my foreign key in the new table for that column, but when I gather the objects in a view; my result-object contains the mapped object from the foreign key constraint as the result-object's property `(i.e. user.client_id = ClientObject)`. It is very clean, I feel like I wasted my time attempting to do this manually, you live and you learn I guess. Thanks again @Daniel Roseman  :)